# How can I read special characters from a table of SQLSERVER in perl?

Tags: sql-server, perl, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

with perl I'm trying to read some records from a SQLSERVER database that has a default charset = Latin1_General_CI_AS

These records have some special characters (for example: à è ì ò ù)

When I extract these records the perl output does not show these special characters.

I tried the encode / decode functions but without success ...

```
use DBI;
# DBD::ADO 
$dsn = "Provider=sqloledb;Trusted Connection=yes;"; 
$dsn .= "Server=$host;Database=$database"; 
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ADO:$dsn",  $user,  $auth, 
 { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1} 
 ) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

$sql = "select idnews, titolo from news where idnews>$ultimoidinserito";

 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute
 or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
  while(@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) 
  {
    $titolo=lc($row[1]);
    $idnews=$row[0];
        print "$titolo\n";
 }
```

Some record expected:

Eurolega la finale sarà CSKA-Efes

Futuro Allegri ecco dove può andare

Result obtained:

Eurolega la finale sarα CSKA-Efes

Futuro Allegri ecco dove pu≥ andare

Comment: 1) Most DBD return the strings *encoded*, so it's up to you to decode them. It sounds from the docs that you can use `Win32::OLE->Option( CP => Win32::OLE::CP_UTF8 );` to set the encoding to UTF-8, making it easy for you to decode them.

Comment: 2) You print to the terminal without first encoding your output.

Comment: About the latter point, see [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1231890)

Comment: Great answer @ikegami7! Problem solved!

It was enough to add the encoding for the standard output:

        require Win32;
    
      my $coe = "cp" . Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP();
      binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding($coe)");


I thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
my $reportJson = to_json($data,{ pretty => 1})
```

use perl "pretty", everything looks good.